# How to completely factor a multivariate polynomial

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following polynomial:

```
f = x1**2 + 2*x1*x2 + 2*x1*x3 + 2*x2**2 + 4*x2*x3 + x3**2
```

I would like to get like this:

```
(x1+x2+x3)**2 + (x2+x3)**2 - x3**2
```

```
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
x1,x2,x3 = sym.symbols('x1 x2 x3')
f = x1**2 + 2*x1*x2 + 2*x1*x3 + 2*x2**2 + 4*x2*x3 + x3**2
fx1 = sym.factor(f,x1)
```

I only get the following:

[image: \displaystyle x_{1}^{2} + x_{1} \cdot \left(2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3}\right) + 2 x_{2}^{2} + 4 x_{2} x_{3} + x_{3}^{2}]

Comment: Do you have an example of how you might simplify that function (or a simpler function with a similar structure) by hand? Sympy, Symbolab, and Wolfram weren't able to simplify it either.